# Connect to Oracle 11.2 with Visual Studio 2012 C++

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio-2012, occi

I am trying to make a connection to Oracle 11.2 using OCCI and Visual Studio 2012 c++.

I have followed the following steps.

1. Get instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0,    instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0 and    instantclient-sqlplus-nt-11.2.0.4.0 and extract to C:  (Then it    should be C:\instantclient_11_2)
2. Extract OCCI for visual studio 2010 (This is the latest version on    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html)
3. Configurations
   In C:\instantclient_11_2\vc10 add the oraocci11.dll and oraocci11d.dll from OCCI.
   In C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10 add the oraocci11d.lib and oraocci11.lib
4. Set the paths in system path variables as       C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10; C:\instantclient_11_2;
5. set the library paths in    project->properties->linker->Input->Additional Dependencies     C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10\oraocci11.lib     C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10\oraocci11d.lib
6. Edit VC++ directories  Include C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\include;$(IncludePath)  Library Directories    : C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10;$(LibraryPath)
7. 64bit configuration environment
8. Tools->Options-Debugging->Symbol->Microsoft Symbol Servers if necessary

The program,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

namespace oc = oracle::occi;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // setup
        oc::Environment* env = oc::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT); // 1

        try{
            oc::Connection* conn = env->createConnection("ASD", "ASD123", "dbName"); // 2
        }
        catch(const oc::SQLException& e){
            std::cout  << e.what() << std::endl; 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }
        oc::Environment::terminateEnvironment(env); 
    }
    catch(const oc::SQLException& e) // 7
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

But I keep getting the following issues,

'testSample4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\lib\msvc\vc10\oraocci11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

and

First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD41ADCD in testSample4.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: oracle::occi::SQLException at memory location 0x000000000031E7E8.

Then get the error : the attribute OCI_ATTR_USERNAME is greater than the maximum allowable length of 255

Can someone help me with this please...

Comment: You are using VS 2012, yet downloaded 2010 libraries?  That isn't going to work too well.  Complain to Oracle that they need to update their libraries -- or get some other C++ wrapper, like this: http://otl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have managed to solve the issue by installing oracle 12 c full client and Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Comment: I have successfully developed this using  Oracle Instant Client Package - Basic (instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip) with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 64bit platform

Comment: This is such an infuriating error and I am having similar issues with vs2015 and occi 12_2 which apparently includes the right stuff....